# Where can I find network adapter drivers (W7x64) for my Asrock P67 Extreme4 MB?

Tags: drivers, motherboard, network-adapter

Couldn't find any of them after scouring the web.
I'm just assuming the network adapter is built in, so that might be where I'm wrong.

Comment: Vista 64bit drivers should work if they are available.

Comment: Found it: Realtek LAN driver at this page: http://www.asrock.com/mb/download.asp?Model=P67%20Extreme4&o=Win764

Comment: Unfortunately my rep is too low to answer my own question before 8 hours.

Comment: Now I can only accept it in 23 hours.

Answer (score 0):

**Found it**: Realtek LAN driver at [this page](http://www.asrock.com/mb/download.asp?Model=P67%20Extreme4&o=Win764).